# How to run Qt Creator from console in Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I don't know how it's called in console.

Tried "qt", "qt-creator", "qtcreator". It not works.

Tried to find where Qt Creator is installed. I didn't find it.

Tried open qt from desktop. "./Qt\ Creator\ (Community)"

Command -ls showing the name as DigiaQt-qtcreator-community.desktop. "./DigiaQt-qtcreator-community.desktop". It doesn't work too.

I need it to run Qt Creator as root.

Comment: For my configuration it works as "qt creator".

Comment: Not works too as "qt creator"

Comment: How did you install it? What version?

Comment: Also, open that .desktop file with text editor. It should have the path to the program (actually to a wrapper script, probably, so you could also look at that and see which binary it launches and how, if you are interested).

Comment: I installed it from .run file like a windows style. Found exec here /opt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator. But Qt don't see old projects. Trying recover them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/opt is owned by root , you need to give permission to user chmod +x qtcreator.

Comment: chmod+x doesn't help, cuz, If I am right, it not gives root permission to qtcreator. And I checked it.

Comment: chmod -v u+s /path/to/yourapp helped to give root permission.